# Muenchian Grouping with XSL-FO Table

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsl-fo, muenchian-grouping

I've been working with producing simple PDFs with XSL-FO in RenderX XEP for a while, but I'm relatively new to the more involved functions of XPath.

I have some XML which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report>
    <ticket>
        <size>A</size>
        <department>Dept 1</department>
        <category>Cat 1</category>
        <product>Product 1</product>
    </ticket>
    <ticket>
        <size>A</size>
        <department>Dept 1</department>
        <category>Cat 2</category>
        <product>Product 2</product>
    </ticket>
    <ticket>
        <size>B</size>
        <department>Dept 1</department>
        <category>Cat 2</category>
        <product>Product 3</product>
    </ticket>
    <ticket>
        <size>B</size>
        <department>Dept 1</department>
        <category>Cat 1</category>
        <product>Product 1</product>
    </ticket>
    <ticket>
        <size>C</size>
        <department>Dept 1</department>
        <category>Cat 2</category>
        <product>Product 2</product>
    </ticket>
    <ticket>
        <size>D</size>
        <department>Dept 3</department>
        <category>Cat 1</category>
        <product>Product 4</product>
    </ticket>
    <ticket>
        <size>D</size>
        <department>Dept 1</department>
        <category>Cat 1</category>
        <product>Product 1</product>
    </ticket>
</report>
```

I need to be able to sort this data into tables into a PDF using XSLT1.0 formatting objects. The desired format being the following:

All tickets of the same size being in separate tables (sorted on the page in alphabetical order), which each list their products, contained within their relevant categories and departments. 
Example:

[image: Desired Output]

I have had a go at implementing Muenchian grouping, but the wrong categories are falling under the departments when using a large XML extract, and I haven't been able to list the relevant products below each category.

My probably rather untidy XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="keySize" match="ticket" use="size" />
    <xsl:key name="keyDepartment" match="ticket" use="concat(size, ' ', department)" />
    <xsl:key name="keyCategory" match="ticket" use="concat(size, ' ', department, ' ', category)" />

    <xsl:template match="/report">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="2cm">
                    <fo:region-body />
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

                    <xsl:for-each select="ticket[count(. | key('keySize', size)[1]) = 1]">
                        <xsl:sort select="size" order="ascending" />
                        <fo:block>
                            Size <xsl:value-of select="size" />
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:variable name="sizes" select="key('keySize', size)" />
                            <xsl:for-each select="$sizes[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyDepartment', concat(size, ' ', department))[1])]">
                                <xsl:sort select="department" order="ascending" />

                                <!--TABLES START-->
                                <fo:table-and-caption>
                                    <fo:table border="0.2mm solid black" width="100%">
                                        <fo:table-header>
                                            <fo:table-row>
                                                <fo:table-cell>
                                                    <fo:block font-weight="bold" margin="1mm 0mm 0mm 1mm">
                                                        <xsl:text>Department</xsl:text>
                                                    </fo:block>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:table-cell>
                                                    <fo:block font-weight="bold" margin="1mm 0mm 0mm 1mm">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="department" />
                                                    </fo:block>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                            </fo:table-row>
                                        </fo:table-header>
                                        <fo:table-body>
                                            <fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:block margin="1mm 0mm 0mm 1mm" />
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                        </fo:table-body>
                                    </fo:table>
                                </fo:table-and-caption>

                                <!--BRINGS IN WRONG CATEGORIES-->
                                <xsl:for-each select="$sizes[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyCategory', concat(size, ' ', department, ' ', category))[1])]">
                                    <xsl:sort select="category" order="ascending" />
                                    <fo:table-and-caption>
                                        <fo:table border="0.2mm solid black" width="100%">
                                            <fo:table-header>
                                                <fo:table-row>
                                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                                        <fo:block font-weight="bold" margin="1mm 0mm 0mm 1mm">
                                                            <xsl:text>Category</xsl:text>
                                                        </fo:block>
                                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                                        <fo:block font-weight="bold" margin="1mm 0mm 0mm 1mm">
                                                            <xsl:value-of select="category" />
                                                        </fo:block>
                                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                                </fo:table-row>
                                            </fo:table-header>
                                            <fo:table-body>
                                                <fo:table-row>
                                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                                        <fo:block margin="1mm 0mm 0mm 1mm"><xsl:value-of select="description" /></fo:block>
                                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                                </fo:table-row>

                                                <!--

                                                DESCRIPTIONS GO HERE?

                                                -->
                                            </fo:table-body>
                                        </fo:table>
                                    </fo:table-and-caption>
                                </xsl:for-each>                         
                            </xsl:for-each>                         
                        </fo:block>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help with bringing in the products would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with this line, where you try to iterate over all categories for a department

```
<xsl:for-each select="$sizes[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyCategory', concat(size, ' ', department, ' ', category))[1])]">
```

The problem is the variable **sizes** contains details on different departments, not just the one you are interested in, leading to duplicates.

Try this instead, to restrict it to the current department

```
<xsl:variable name="depts" select="key('keyDepartment', concat(size, ' ', department))" />
<xsl:for-each select="$depts[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyCategory', concat(size, ' ', department, ' ', category))[1])]">
```

Comment: That is a big help, thanks! The departments are now just listing their relevant categories. The next trick is to list all of the products relevant to each category. Do I need a new key to perform this or is there a way to use the content of the current group? How would I set up the xsl:for-each for that?

Comment: Just do an xsl:for-each look over the current key `xsl:for-each select="key('keyCategory', concat(size, ' ', department, ' ', category))/product">`

Comment: ...and that's the icing on the cake. That's helped my understanding considerably and helped me solve another issue I had. Thank you very much sir!